# Does inserting/updating/deleting record auto update indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, rebuild

Does inserting/ updating or deleting a record in DB auto update the indexes?

I've seen rebuild commands for indexes and I just can't understand if I have to do all these manually, then what's the purpose of indexes. This is so inconvenient that I spend time rebuilding the indexes every week or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When index fragmentation becomes too high, indexes will be very inefficient. There is need to rebuild index.

[Let SQL Server Tell You Which Indexes to Rebuild](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2009/01/05/6819737.aspx)

Rebuilding an index drops and re-creates the index. This removes fragmentation, reclaims disk space by compacting the pages based on the existing fill factor setting, and reorders the index rows in contiguous pages.

[Reorganizing and Rebuilding Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you `insert, update, or delete` a row, any indexes on that table automatically reflect the change.